# Setting Enivironment Variables in Bash script for use with AWS CLI

Tags: bash, environment-variables, aws-cli

I'm trying to set environment variables required for making requests to AWS via AWS CLI in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal by running a bash script, rather than having to manually set my environment variables using export within the shell.

I have confirmed that the AWS credentials I am using are still active as they work when I set the environment variables from the shell and also work via the AWS credentials file. So I figure it must be something wrong with the way I am passing the value to the environment variable.

I've tried surrounding with quotes, but as i'm new to this am at a loss as to where to go next.

```
#!/bin/bash
unset AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
unset AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
file="/path/to/accessKeys.csv"
cnt=0
 export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
 export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=text
while IFS=, read var1 var2  
do 

      if [ $cnt = 1 ]
      then 
        echo $cnt
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$var1
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$var2
      fi

      cnt=$(($cnt + 1))

done < $file
```

when I run AWS configure list I get the following output

```
:~$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************C4JA              env    
              env    **********6YS
    region                us-east-1              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

When I run env to see environment variables the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY appears to be correct, though output I am expecting from AWS configure list(output I get when I manually set variable using export within shell)

```
~$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************C4JA              env    
secret_key     ****************j6YS              env    
    region                us-east-1              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

Output from `AWS configure list | tr -d '\r'`

```
:~$ aws configure list | tr -d '\r'
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************C4JA              env    
secret_key     ****************6YS              env    
    region                us-east-1              env    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

but this gives SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

Any help or pointers on this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Does it help when you run `aws configure list | tr -d '\r'`?

Comment: How are you running the script? You will need to `source` the script to be able to set environment variables in the current shell session.

Comment: Yeah, I am sourcing script to run in current shell, and the environment variables show up after I have run the script.

Comment: You are sourcing OK, but can help future users by adding this line: `(return 0 2>/dev/null) || { printf "%s\n" "Start in current shell with" "   source $0" ; exit 1 ; }
`

Comment: using `aws configure list | tr -d '\r'` makes the output look almost correct. (will edit question to show output) but I still get a signature does not match error when I try to run AWS CLI commands.

Comment: See answer: your current script adds '\r' to the key, and adding this character makes the key invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `file="/path/to/accessKeys.csv"` is in Windows format (with `\r`).
The secret key has been set to `*****j6YS\r`.

You can replace the last line `done < $file` with

```
done < <(tr -d '\r' < "${file}" )
```

or only get the second line with

```
done < <(sed -n '2s/\r*//p' "${file}" )
```

You do not need a loop

```
IFS=, read -d'' -r AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY < <(sed -n '2s/\r*//p' "${file}" )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, works perfectly. Not to bother you too much, but do you have any pointers towards where I could read why file is in Windows format, or how I can know this? Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Most files created/edit on windows are with \r, unless you changed the settings of your editor. You can use `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r' < infputfile` for deleting chars, or check with `grep -c "^M" file` (insert ^M as one character by CTRL-V CTRL-M).
When this works, you can accept the answer.